# How much ram can I install in my Compaq A900 computer?

Tags: ram

I would love to know how much usable RAM I can install in this Compaq A900 computer.  No idea how to tell, just started using Ubuntu this week.

Intel® Pentium(R) Dual CPU T2370 @ 1.73GHz × 2
Intel® 965GM chipset
64-bit Ubuntu 13.10
2.9 GiB

Comment: There are many different models of the Compaq A910. Would you please check the underside for the exact model number, click on the grey _edit_ link above, and put that in your original question?

Answer (score 2):

Pages 10 and 94 of the [manual PDF](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01295803.pdf) suggests it is now at maximum memory, as does [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/upgrade/HP+-+Compaq-memory/Presario+Notebooks/Presario+a900+Series-upgrades.html#), a high-profile memory vendor. It is not uncommon for 2007-vintage laptops to max out at 4GB or less.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, both crucial and hp say 2gb is max and you have 3gb. Unless it's a typo. This happens sometimes when the motherboard bios is upgraded, the memory capacity is increased without being documented. Assuming one of your chips is 1gb you will likely be able to change it to a 2gb, but no guarantees. It happened to me with a thinkpad. If that works, 4 is probably max.